# Cleveref for items in hypothesis

Tags: cleveref

consider the snippet below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  naturalnames=false,
  hypertexnames=false,
  breaklinks
}
  
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}
  \begin{hypothesis}\label{hyp:general}
    This is a general hypothesis which contains two subordinate hypotheses
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{hyp:first} First hypothesis
      \item \label{hyp:second} Second hypothesis
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{hypothesis}

This is a reference to the general \cref{hyp:general}, and this to the
second subordinate \cref{hyp:general}.\labelcref{hyp:second}.
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

The general reference is displayed correctly, but the subordinate hypothesis is badly cross-referenced, because it produces a black dot, instead of a blue dot, between **Hypothesis 1** and **2**.

How can I write a command such that the dot is displayed in exactly the same colour and style used for the Hypothesis? Note, that I am not after a solution that specifically paints the dot blue. I would rather want a solution that automatically inherits the colour specified in the hyper setup command

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle I have now rewritten the question from scratch.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot to illustrate your MWE. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you (a) create a bespoke enumerate-type environment called `hypoenum` with the help of the `enumitem` package and (b) tailor cross-references to enumerated items in a `hypoenum` environment to (i) use the hypothesis number as a prefix to the item number when creating cross-references and (ii) inform `cleveref` which text label it should use when creating cross-references to enumerated items in a `hypoenum` environment.

A separate comment: I suggest using the upright font shape for the enumeration in a theorem-like environment. This helps the reader make distinctions between what's the content and what's structure or "architecture", if you prefer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}

\usepackage{enumitem} % for \newlist and \setlist macros
\newlist{hypoenum}{enumerate}{1} % associated counter name: 'hypoenumi`.
\setlist[hypoenum]{label=\upshape\arabic*.,
                   ref=\upshape\thehypothesis.\arabic*}
\crefname{hypoenumi}{hypothesis}{hypotheses}

\begin{document}
\begin{hypothesis}\label{hyp:general}
This is a general hypothesis which comprises two subordinated hypotheses:
   \begin{hypoenum}
   \item \label{hyp:first}  First hypothesis
   \item \label{hyp:second} Second hypothesis
   \end{hypoenum}
\end{hypothesis}

\medskip\noindent
This is a cross-reference to the general \cref{hyp:general}, 
and this is one to the subordinated \cref{hyp:second}.
  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  naturalnames=false,
  hypertexnames=false,
  breaklinks
}
  
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}
\newcommand\refhypo[2]{\hyperref[#1]{\cref*{#1}.}\labelcref{#2}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{hypothesis}\label{hyp:general}
    This is a general hypothesis which contains two subordinate hypotheses
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \label{hyp:first} First hypothesis
      \item \label{hyp:second} Second hypothesis
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{hypothesis}

This is a reference to the general \cref{hyp:general}, and this to the second 
subordinate \refhypo{hyp:general}{hyp:second}. 
  
 \end{document}
```